# Error when estimating treatment effects with synth_runner

Tags: stata

I am using the *community-contributed* command `synth_runner` to estimate the treatment effect of a forest conservation policy, using time-series land cover data (three time periods).

I want to compare farms that enroll in the conservation program (treated in `t=3`) to a synthetic control. My dataset has ~`1500` observations, and I am using only `3` covariates per the code:

```
synth_runner percent_oldforest total_ha slope_mean dist_hwy, d(DID)
```

Variable `DID` is a dummy indicating treated or not in the last time period.

The model is taking ~`15` minutes to run and continually ends with the following error:

> Error estimating treatment effect for unit 363, or some other unit.

I have increased my `matsize` to `2000` but this does not solve the problem.

Is there a way to troubleshoot why there is an error and how I could identify and remove any observations that may generate this error?

Answer (score 2):

The errors for this awesome command can be frustratingly cryptic. Some of this probably has to do with it being a wrapper for `synth`.

It is hard to know for sure since I cannot replicate your analysis, but if I had to guess it has to do with missing outcome data or unit names that are too long or a lack of variation on a covariate. There are probably other ways to get this error that I have not enumerated.

Here is an example showing the first problem:

```
use "synth_smoking.dta", clear
xtset state year
gen byte D = (state==3 & year>=1989)
synth_runner cigsale beer(1984(1)1988) lnincome(1972(1)1988) retprice age15to24 cigsale(1988) cigsale(1980) cigsale(1975), d(D)
replace cigsale =. if state=="Alabama":state & year==1985
synth_runner cigsale beer(1984(1)1988) lnincome(1972(1)1988) retprice age15to24 cigsale(1988) cigsale(1980) cigsale(1975), d(D)
```

You can get a similar error when the unit names are too long:

```
egen state2 = group(state state state), label
xtset state2 year
synth_runner cigsale beer(1984(1)1988) lnincome(1972(1)1988) retprice age15to24 cigsale(1988) cigsale(1980) cigsale(1975), d(D)
```

Finally, if a covariate is constant for all units in one time period, same problem:

```
replace beer = 0 if year==1979
synth_runner cigsale beer(1979) beer(1984(1)1988) lnincome(1972(1)1988) retprice age15to24 cigsale(1988) cigsale(1980) cigsale(1975), d(D)
```

All of these yield:

```
Error estimating treatment effect for unit 3
invalid syntax
r(198);
```

If this does not fix things, try `set trace on` and try to see where the error happens and add that to your question. If you drop some of the untreated observations, that might also speed things up for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: (I'm the `synth_runner` author) Yes, errors can be hard to diagnose because of the wrapping. Use `trace` or find the unit the error happens on and then run `synth` on just that unit. The first error you note is actually missing outcome data (which might mean you'll need to drop that year), whereas missing covariate data should be handled fine and happens in the original `smoking` data. Issues 2 & 3 are just problems/constrains with `synth`.

Comment: @BeingQuisitive I don't quite understand what "actually" means in your comment. Isn't that what I have written in the second paragraph (missing outcome data)?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There was a question on my GitHub repo about problems with missing covariates and it linked here. I assumed it was the same issue and didn't read carefully enough. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: @BeingQuisitive No problem. It looks like I misread the GitHub issue myself when I linked to this post. Thanks for developing the synth_runner package and answering our questions.

Comment: This is simply an addition to the already accepted answer above, which is very complete.

A fourth source of this error can be created by having too many potential time periods in your data set. The cap seems to be roughly 200-250 periods in practice.

Comment: @RegressForward Too many pre or post periods will generate "expression too long
r(130)" error. The limit comes from the limit on inlist(). See [this post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1521802-expression-too-long-error-while-finding-synthetic-control?p=1557995#post1557995) on Statalist for more details and MVE.